# Prophecy in Surah Rum

Tags: quran

Assalamualaikum,

The prophecy about the defeat of Romans (Byzantines) against Persians (Sassanids) is described in the beginning verses of Surah Rum.

Does anyone have an idea which exact battle is talked about in this verse in which the Romans were defeated?

It also states "Adn-al-Ard" as the land where it happened. This might be translated as "the lowest land".
Which lowest land is the verse referring to?
(The area around dead sea is quite low in elevation, but which exact battle took place there?)